# Pattern matching using list of characters

Tags: performance, prolog, call, predicate, evaluation

I am having difficulty pattern matching words which are converted to lists of characters:

```erlang
wordworm(H1,H2,H3,V1,V2) :-
    word(H1), string_length(H1,7), 
    word(H2), string_length(H2,5),
    word(H3), string_length(H3,4),
    word(V1), string_length(V1,4), 
       word(H3) \= word(V1),
       atom_chars(H2, [_,_,Y,_,_]) = atom_chars(V1, [_,_,_,Y]),
    word(V2), string_length(V2,5), 
       word(H2) \= word(V2),
       atom_chars(H3, [_,_,_,Y]) = atom_chars(V2, [_,_,_,_,Y]).
```

Above this section, I have a series of 600 words in the format, `word("prolog")`. The code runs fine, without the `atom_chars`, but with it, I get a *time-out* error. Can anyone suggest a better way for me to structure my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog predicate calls are *not* like function calls in other languages. They do *not* have "return values".

When you write `X = atom_chars(foo, Chars)` this does *not* execute `atom_chars`. It builds a *data structure* `atom_chars(foo, Chars)`. It does not "call" this data structure.

If you want to evaluate `atom_chars` on some atom `H2` and then say something about the resulting list, call it like:

```
atom_chars(H2, H2Chars),
H2Chars = [_,_,Y,_,_]
```

So overall maybe your code should look more like this:

```
...,
atom_chars(H2, H2Chars),
H2Chars = [_,_,Y,_,_],
atom_chars(V1, V1Chars),
V1Chars = [_,_,_,Y],
...
```

Note that you don't need to assert some kind of "equality" between these `atom_chars` goals. The fact that their char lists share the same variable `Y` means that there will be a connection: The third character of `H2` must be equal to the fourth character of `V1`.

Comment: ... and don't forget to move every goal as high up in the overall predicate as possible, to avoid needless re-generation of the same answer. specifically, `atom_chars(H2, [_,_,Y,_,_])` needs to go right after `word(H2), string_length(H2,5)`. and BTW this obviates the need for the `length` call altogether, because `[_,_,Y,_,_]` already says "5 characters".